# Digital door lock standard protocol

Tags: bluetooth

**What's the standard protocol used by digital door locks that are managed through Bluetooth devices?** Like Android and iOS devices.

While digital locks and [Epic](https://epic.co.kr/) works with Android app like [KeyWe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guardtec.keywe&hl=en&gl=US) little is known as to how both communicate through Bluetooth. I wonder if there exists a standard protocol.

My goal is to build an IoT setup where all our digital locks can be managed through the internet through a Bluetooth gateway or gateways that connect to all the locks in the building.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "standard" protocol for digital locks.

That may eventually change as [Matter](https://csa-iot.org/all-solutions/matter/) is more widely adopted and broadens its reach, but for now each lock does it their own way.

Edit: I'll add that many locks support Apple's [HomeKit](https://developer.apple.com/homekit/) in addition to their own home-brewed protocols, but HomeKit is not a standard, it's a proprietary framework and protocol used by Apple devices.